# Error al publicar una aplicación web ASP.NET en IIS

Tags: windows-server

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto de Angular con .NET Core, el proyecto lo publique en la ruta:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App
```

Para ingresarlo como Agregar aplicación así:

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\App
```

Ya que esta guardada en esa ruta : *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App*

quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Default Web Site esta configurado así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si le doy inspeccionar me sale en esta ruta:

```
http://localhost/AppIntranet/
```

Pero se queda así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con estos errores

```
GET http://localhost/styles.6a1a4a997409fd154a76.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:13          GET http://localhost/js/runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:16          GET http://localhost/js/polyfills-es2015.c5a2978b4838dfa2931e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:18          GET http://localhost/js/main-es2015.2351de683bb684365cd3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:17          GET http://localhost/js/scripts.5357b40d9937c390d421.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Siendo que el archivo launchSettings.json tiene esta configuración

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:80",
      "sslPort": 44391
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IntranetV2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:80;http://localhost:80",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Si accedo a la carpeta donde esta guardado y utilizo el comando dotnet Intranetv2.ddl este esta sobre el puerto 5000 o 5001

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta funcionando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual puede ser el error?